# Можно ли увеличить количество повторений цикла изнутри самого цикла?

Tags: c#, циклы

Можно ли увеличить количество повторений цикла из него же? Простой пример:

```
a = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    if (f)
        a++;
}
```

Comment: Можно, конечно. Именно так, как вы и написали. Вы бы просто попробовали :)

Comment: Может, число итераций? Если так, то да, вы спокойно можете изменять значение `i` изнутри цикла.

Comment: @Arhad, вроде, это считается плохой практикой в цикле for, если я не ошибаюсь. Первый взгляд на цикл for дает уверенность, что он закончится через n-итераций цикла. Когда что-то нужно менять, то цикл while лучше, так как ты сразу ожидаешь, что логика выхода находится в коде.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Согласен. Но вы это адептам `break` и `return` внутри `while` скажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если переменная `а` не `const` или не `readonly`, то да. Элементарно можно было запустить это в вижле и после цикла написать `Console.Write(a);`

В примере число повторений цикла увеличивается не изнутри, а внутри. А если надо, чтобы увеличивалось изнутри, то в параметры метода Foo нужно поместить переменную `а` с модификатором `ref` или `out`(чтобы после завершения метода переменная `a` изменилась). Либо сделать bool Foo(f), а уже в самом цикле в зависимости от результата выполнения метода Foo изменять или не изменять `a`

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы можете менять значения переменных, которые находятся в цикле `for`, что бы продлить его работу, НО на мой взгляд, это плохая практика.

От цикла `for`, когда на него смотришь не ожидаешь, что где-то в цикле запрятана дополнительная логика и ожидаешь простую итерацию, которая имеет конечное кол-во повторений.

Поэтому для целей, которые вы описали лучше использовать `while`, так как его упоминание сразу говорит, что нужно искать логику выхода из него где-то внутри.

Comment: Эй, кто меня минуснул? Хоть бы аргумент написали.